# how to iterate through json array

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

**How do we iterate through the `Map` array?**

My payload looks like this:

```
{
  "Record": "...bunch of hl7 data...",
  "Map": [{ "DG1.2": "PatientDiag1" }, { "DG1.3": "PatientDiag2" }]
}
```

**How do we iterate and parse the values of the `Map` array?**

I've tried the following:

```
var blobObject = JObject.Parse(blob); 
var map = blobObject["Map"];  //it's a JToken at this point
//now let's parse each key/value pair in the map:
foreach (var field in map)
{

    var key = field.ToString();
    var value = field[0].Value
}
```

Comment: what's the result of your tried code?

Comment: you should map your JSON to class and create `JsonConverter`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"Map"` is an **array of JSON objects**, so first you need to loop through the array, then you can loop through the key/value pairs of each object:

```
var blobObject = JObject.Parse(blob); 
var map = blobObject["Map"];  //it's a JToken at this point
//now let's parse each key/value pair in the map:
foreach (var item in map.Cast<JObject>()) //  Map is an array of objects so loop through the array, then loop through the key/value pairs of each object
{
    foreach (var pair in item)
    {
        var key = pair.Key;
        var value = pair.Value;
    }
}
```

Or if you prefer to flatten the array with LINQ's [`SelectMany()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany):

```
foreach (var pair in map.SelectMany(o => (IDictionary<string, JToken>)o))
{
    var key = pair.Key;
    var value = pair.Value;
}
```

Notes:

1. From the [JSON spec](https://www.json.org/json-en.html)

   > JSON is built on two structures:
   >
   > - A collection of name/value pairs. In various languages, this is realized as an object, record, struct, dictionary, hash table, keyed list, or associative array.
   > - An ordered list of values. In most languages, this is realized as an array, vector, list, or sequence.

   A JSON array is mapped to a [`JArray`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray.htm) while a JSON object is mapped to a [`JObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm).
2. *How do we ... parse the values of the Map array?*  You don't need to *parse* the values of the `Map` array, they are already fully parsed.  You just need to query them with [LINQ to JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm).

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OUK2eE).

Answer (score 1):

```
    var blobObject = JObject.Parse(blob);
    var map = blobObject["Map"];
    var values = map.Values().OfType<JProperty>();
    foreach (JProperty prop in values)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(prop.Name); // property name
        Console.WriteLine(prop.Value);// property value
    }
```

Get all the values from `Map` key as `JProperty`, then loop through each property and you can access the property name using `prop.Name` and the value using `prop.Value`.